# How could I’ll be initiated with a mantra Japa when living in Belgium and not knowing any guru personally. I’m a fervent seeker of Sw Sarvapriyananda

Tags: mantras, vivekananda, initiation, japa, appayya-dikshitar

To well pursued my quest towards self realisation I need to be initiated to a mantra Diksha and have not be able to found a guru in my home town

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Take a tour of the site before get started. Please note that we do not allow personal advice questions.

Comment: Go to https://www.vedantany.org/contact-us/ and contact directly Swami Sarvapriyananda.

Comment: If you are sincere your guru will find you. Keep praying sincerely and your guru will come to you.